# Is it possible to use LINQ to detect duplicate adjacent characters?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to verify that a string does not contain any duplicate characters (from a set of bad characters) in adjacent positions. Previous stack overflow answers on this subject seem to mostly be of the general form:

```
for(int i = 0; i < testString.Length-1; i++){
    if(testString[i] == testString[i+1] && testString[i] == badChar){
        //Handle rejection here
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this kind of verification/validation in LINQ? More generically: is it possible within LINQ to compare the value of each character in a string to the next character in a

`testString.Any(c => /*test goes here*/)` call?

Comment: look at the [MoreLINQ library](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ), specifically [`GroupAdjacent`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/GroupAdjacent.cs) - you can see the tests [here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq.Test/GroupAdjacentTest.cs) for examples. (If you don't want to use the library itself it'll at least show you how it can be done.)

Comment: Alternatively, regex might work for you.

Comment: regex you can just ([badchars])\1

Comment: Actually, @johnny5, I think that should be the answer.

Comment: @GertArnold yeah it's simple, but a lot of dev's don't like regex, there is an old say, that it seems developers today go by  "A developer had a problem, he though he would solve with regex, now he has two problems"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anytime you have a class that has `Count` (or equivalent) property and indexer, you can use [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) as base for the LINQ query and perform inside an indexed access similar to the non LINQ code:

```
bool test = Enumerable.Range(0, testString.Length - 1).Any(i = > 
        testString[i] == testString[i + 1] && testString[i] == badChar)
```

Comment: I marked this because it seems to be the closest to what I initially wanted, but since it is so similar to the loop method anyway, I think that I'll probably end up just using that.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Pairwise` from [moreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) library:

```
if(testString.Pairwise((n, m) => new {n, m}).Any(x => x.n == x.m && x.n == badChar))
    // do something
```

If you want to use pure LINQ you could hack it with `Skip`/`Zip` combination:

```
if(testString.Zip(testString.Skip(1), (n, m) => new {n, m})).Any(x => x.n == x.m && x.n == badChar))
    // do something
```

But both these solutions will be much slower then `for` loop-based solution, so I'd advice against doing that.

Comment: _This_ is what I was looking for in my comment above - I _knew_ moreLINQ had something purpose-built for it.

Answer (score 3):

How about the egregious misuse of the aggregate function? I like to think this answer is more of an example of what not to do, even if it is possible. A while and string.indexOf are probably the most appropriate to this problem.

```
var items = "ab^cdeef##gg";
var badChars = new[] {'^', '#', '~'};
var doesAdjacentDupeExist = false;
var meaninglessAggregate = items.Aggregate((last, current) => 
    {
        if (last == current && badChars.Contains(last))
        {
            doesAdjacentDupeExist = true;
        };
        return current;
    });
```

This is not as clever, but it does work. It trades the setting of an outside variable inside the query (bad), for relying on index and elementAt (not great).

```
var items = "abcdefffghhijjk";
var badChars = new[] { 'f', 'h' };
var indexCieling = items.Count() - 1;
var badCharIndexes = items.Select((item, index) => 
    {
        if (index >= indexCieling)
        {
            return null as int?;
        }
        else
        {
            if (item == items.ElementAt(index + 1) && badChars.Contains(item))
            {
                return index as int?;
            }
            else
            {
                return null as int?;
            }
        }
    });
var doesAdjacentDupeExist = badCharIndexes.Any(x => x.HasValue);
```